# Device driver: Windows ReadFile function timeout

Tags: c++, windows, timeout, device-driver, readfile

I am using a device driver that occasionaly misses an interrupt from hardware.

To read data from the device, I use the function

```
  BOOL WINAPI ReadFile(
   __in         HANDLE hFile,
   __out        LPVOID lpBuffer,
   __in         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
   __out_opt    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
   __inout_opt  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
  );
```

This function blocks forever when the device driver misses an interrupt. This results in the program stalling, and one has to restart windows to resolve it.

To fix this, I want to use a timeout-limit when calling Readfile(). But when I use

```
  BOOL WINAPI SetCommTimeouts(
   __in  HANDLE hFile,
   __in  LPCOMMTIMEOUTS lpCommTimeouts
  );
```

it fails with error code 87 (invalid parameters). Apparently, I can't use this timeout stuff on a device driver handle. How can I fix this? Is there some other way to set a timeout limit on a device driver?

thanks

Comment: Probably [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial.aspx) library is useful for you.

Comment: SetCommTimeouts is for serial I/O, not generic device driver I/O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to switch to asynchronous I/O.  Open the device driver supplying the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag to [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then pass an overlapped structure when you call  [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The handle will be signaled when the i/o completes so you can use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx) where you supply the Handle passed to ReadFile and a timeout.

Not all device drivers support asynch I/O so this may not actually work for you.  If this is the case, the [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will still block and not return "ERROR_PENDING_IO".

If you timeout, you should also call [CancelIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363791%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to kill the ReadFile before the overlapped structure goes out of scope.  Otherwise, if it happens to finish later, it'll try to write the memory the overlapped structure used to live in.

Asynch i/o is a bit tricky to get right so read the docs carefully.

**Update:** An alternative occurred to me that you can call [CancelIEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363792%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from a watchdog thread.  Being a newer API, it may not be present on the platforms you have to support.